# How to look up a specific Google phrase having punctuation in it

Tags: google-search

Before run `yum remove ceph-release`, I would like to look up ceph-release. But quotes like ' and " still brings results like ceph releases, release ceph. So how to look up exactly "ceph-release"?

That was just an example. I would like to know how to look up an exact phrase like "a-b", having punctuation in it.

Answer (score 2):

### General case

If you add or remove punctuation characters from a search term Google will often automatically suggest a correction for you.

1. Example search phrase: `air tight`
   Google knows what the search term `air tight` means.

   [image]
2. Example search phrase: `fire fly`
   Google suggests what is possibly a more exact search term than `fire fly`.

   [image]
3. Example search phrase: `50/50` returns no useful results, but the more explicit search phrase `50/50 chance` does return useful results. Google knows exactly what `50/50` means only if it's made explicit by appending the word `chance` to the search phrase.

### Special case

ceph-release is sometimes enclosed by curly braces to denote whatever release of Ceph (e.g. Hammer, Giant, Firefly, etc.), where the substitution with a particular release should be typed by the user. Google does not seem to know about a ceph-release package.

Search Google for explicit references to a ceph-release package.

```
package search ceph-release
```

Google still does not seem to know about a ceph-release package. Visit [Get Packages — Ceph Documentation](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/install/get-packages/) (the first Google search result) and scroll down to the **Add Ceph** heading which lists information about all the major Ceph releases.

Google, Yahoo and Bing will all ignore some symbols, even if you use double quotes. [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com) does return results with special characters, however searching SymbolHound for `ceph-release` returns `0 results found for ceph-release`.

SymbolHound knows approximately what the search phrase `command-line` means, but Google knows exactly what `command-line` means. The first Google search result for `command-line` explicitly defines it and even provides a screenshot of the command-line interface.

Comment: Actually that was just an example. I would like to know how to look up an exact phrase like "a-b", having punctuation in it.

Comment: I only want to look up "ceph-release" with a hyphen in it, but google returns ceph release. This happens especially lookup up command arguments. So how to make google ceph-release but not ceph release?